# Automatically go to next ViewController

Tags: ios, viewcontroller

I am wondering if there is a way to automatically go to another ViewController after an certain number of seconds... I am trying to create a splash screen, but I don't want to use a launch image. Does anyone have any experience with this? Thanks!

Comment: Use an NSTimer to count down to the number of seconds you want, and then go.

Comment: NSTimer would work... but how do I connect a segue from one ViewController to another ViewController without any buttons?

Comment: You can create a segue from the viewcontroller directly, it doesn't have to originate from a button. The only thing you have to do then (and Xcode will remind you of it, via a warning, if you don't), is to name the segue with a unique segue identifier. You then call the segue programmatically using the "performseguewithidentifier" function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your storyboard, create a segue from the splash screen view controller to the home page view controller (your splash screen's destination).  Rename the segue identifier to "HomePageSegue".

In SplashScreenViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"HomePageSegue" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"HomePageSegue"]) {

        // Get destination view
        UIViewController *homeVC = [segue destinationViewController];

        // Pass the information to your destination view
        [self presentViewController:homeVC animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
}
```

This will present the home page as soon as soon as the splash screen loaded.  Feel free to create a timer before `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]` is called.

Comment: Xcode won't let me use "HomePageViewController *homeVC = [segue destinationViewController];" I had to change it to UIViewController *homeVC... will this still work?

Comment: It looks like I have to "#import "HomePageViewController.h" to make it work. But now I am just getting a black screen when I start my app... The Navigation Controller is the initial screen, which is connected to the Splash Screen. The Splash Screen is connected to the Home Page Screen via a segue that has the identifier "HomePageSegue". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try replacing HomePageViewController with UIViewController.

Comment: Yep sorry use UIViewController instead of HomePageViewController.  I was using HomePageViewController as an arbitrary name to distinguish it is the page after your splash screen view controller.